# Pretty url on yii2 routes with # char

Tags: php, yii2

Is it possible to insert # char on routes on main.php file.

For example:

`'#<tag:\S+>' => 'site/tag'`

I would like to have pretty url like `www.site.com/#tag` which performs the actionTag on siteControlles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible because hash variables aren't sent to the server side at all.

Check [RFC 1808](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1808.html)

> Section 2.4.1
>
> "Note that the fragment identifier is not considered part of the URL."

You should use some javascript to convert `#yourtag` to param (`?tag=yourtag`) and send it to the server.

Comment: Thank you, that answer I expected.